# How to add some content to all pages on virtual host in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have different static websites configured as virtual hosts in nginx.

Every website is multiple .html files (lots of code is duplicated).

How can I add scripts/styles to all pages at one domain at once via nginx config? Is this possible?

For example, I want to add googletagmanager script to all pages (inside ) and  for google-site-verification without touching these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the simplest possible solution I can think of is to move your original config from port 80 to 8080 and proxy_pass 80 to 8080

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name  xyz;
   set $domain_script '
       <script>alert("Added by nginx"); </script>
   ';

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      sub_filter '<head>' '<head>$domain_script';
   }
}

server {
   listen 8080;
   # <!-- original config goes here-->
}
```

I ran a sample test and worked perfectly fine for me

[image: nginx modified html]

The only thing assumed is that each page has `<head>` tag